# Why is this INSERT not working? (PHP MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm simply trying to insert a record into a MySQL databse.  Why is this not working?

File name: insert.php

```
<?php

$l_dbhost = "x.x.x.x";
$l_dbuser = "dbuser";
$l_dbpass = "password";
$l_db = "db";
$l_table = "db.users";
$l_datetime = date_create()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$l_username = "bob";
$l_password = "bobpass";

$db_conn = mysqli_connect($l_dbhost, $l_dbuser, $l_dbpass, $l_db) or die("Failed to connect!");

$db_query = "INSERT INTO $l_table (username, password, lastUpdate) VALUES ('$l_username', '$l_password', '$l_datetime')";

echo $db_query . "\n";

$db_result = mysql_query($db_conn, $db_query) or die("Failed to update table!");
?>
```

Here is the output from executing 'php insert.php'...

```
INSERT INTO users (username, password, lastUpdate) VALUES ('bob', 'bobpass', '2016-06-22 21:03:06')
PHP Warning:  mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /var/www/example.com/insert.php on line 19
Failed to update table!
```

MySQL table info:

```
mysql> describe users;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| username   | varchar(45) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| password   | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| lastUpdate | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Thanks for your feedback!
TXBrew

Comment: use `mysqli_query()` instead of `mysql_query()`, dont' mix it

Comment: What an interesting mix of mysqli_ and mysql_.

Answer (score 0):

you are combining a mysqli query and a mysql query:

```
$db_conn = mysqli_connect($l_dbhost, $l_dbuser, $l_dbpass, $l_db) or die("Failed to connect!");
$db_result = mysql_query($db_conn, $db_query) or die("Failed to update table!");
```

should both be mysqli or pdo and avoid mysql queries since they are old and deprecated.

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: Wow... Thanks gavgrif! That was a little embarrassing!  Sorry for not catching the mix of mysqli_ and mysql_ !!!  That's what I get for copy/pasting from different examples!